# How to make my background image not going out its div

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm new. I've created a `<div>` inside a `<section>` and in this `<div>` I've added two background images using Gridlex. For some reasons, both photo go out of the container. I'd like to do something so both pictures don't go out of the container and take all the space of their Gridlex block.

Anyone, would know what I can do to fix this?

Here the photo:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrkkK.jpg)

Here the CSS I've wrote for both images:

```css
.bg-about1 {
  background-image: url('../images/about1.jpg') ;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.bg-about2 {
  background-image: url('../images/about2.jpg') ;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<section class="light-bg section-about">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="col-5_sm12-middle">
                <h2 class="padded-7p center uppercase p-white">Title.</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7_sm12-middle bg-about1">
                <!-- <img class="img100" src="./images/about1.jpg" alt="Art design">  -->
            </div>
            <div class="col-5_sm12-middle bg-about2">
                <!-- <img class="img100" src="./images/about2.jpg" alt="photo"> --> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-7_sm12-middle">
                <p class="padded-2 p-white"> my text.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Have you tried without the minimum height? Images might be just too big?

Answer (score 1):

maybe try instead of
background-size: cover;
writing:
background-size: contain;

Comment: Thank you for your replu. I've tried this as well. I think the problem is from gridlex and negative space maybe? I'm not sure